# Define spring bean destroy method order

Tags: java, spring

I have two beans `BeanA` and `BeanB` with destroy method defined by `DisposableBean`.

There is a requirement that the destroy method of `BeanB` must be invoked after the destroy method of `BeanA`.

How to implement that?

Comment: Are they singletons? Or is scope of bean prototype?

Comment: Yes both are singletons.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you mentioned in comment beans are singletons, you can use `depends_on`.
See Spring framework reference says as follows [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/core.html#beans-factory-dependson)

> The depends-on attribute can specify both an initialization-time
> dependency and, in the case of singleton beans only, a corresponding
> destruction-time dependency. Dependent beans that define a depends-on
> relationship with a given bean are destroyed first, prior to the given
> bean itself being destroyed. Thus, depends-on can also control
> shutdown order.

If you prefer to use annotation based solution, you can use `@DependsOn`. [Javadoc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/DependsOn.html) says as follows:

> Dependent beans that define a depends-on relationship with a given
> bean are destroyed first, prior to the given bean itself being
> destroyed. Thus, a depends-on declaration can also control shutdown
> order.

Comment: You mean that I should annotate @DependsOn("beanA") on the destroy method of the beanB, right?

Comment: @梁雨生 On your bean definition

Comment: What if beanA and beanB depend on each other?